# Why won't my project generated from cmake find the library it created?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to learn cmake by using their [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html).  In step 2, it coaches the user through creation of a library.  Visual Studio appears to not be able to find the MathFunctions.lib which was created in the process.  It does indeed exist, but in the debug folder.  Is there a general way to make sure the library is found without having to add statements such as:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathFunctions/Debug")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathFunctions/Release")
```

This seems like a silly solution and inconsistent with cross platform intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authors of tutorial keep back a little. They are not showing the sources of `MathFunctions.h` and `mysqrt.cxx`. It is not needed on UNIX but on Windows you have to explicitly mark all functions exported/imported from library. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx (unfortunately I have no good tutorial to point to).

If you are not exporting/importing the symbols then linker will not be able to resolve your function and build will fail in despite of the correctly generated cmake project.